# Gem for Multiple table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi Table Inheritance with rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022802/multi-table-inheritance-with-rails-3)

What is the best way to implement MTI in Rails? I don't want to go deep into it, I just want to use ready gem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022802/multi-table-inheritance-with-rails-3

Comment: Check out the [`acts_as_relation`](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation) gem that simulates MTI inheritance through Rails' STI mechanism. Works with Rails 4, too!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a gem, but this blog entry is VERY straightforward and makes sense for 'simulating' MTI with ActiveRecord.

http://mediumexposure.com/multiple-table-inheritance-active-record/