# Rails Associations + Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, inheritance, associations

I'm having trouble deciding how to model the following with rails associations.

The UML would look something like below:

```
----------------
|   CRITERIA   |
----------------
       |
       |*
----------------
|   CONTROLS   | <___
----------------     \
      ^               \
      |                \
-------------------    -------------------
|   SCALE CONTROL |    |  TEXT CONTROL   |      .....
-------------------    -------------------
```

-The various controls have quite different attributes so STI seems like a poor choice.
-A user can specify any number of controls per criteria.

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
Criteria
has_many :controls

ScaleControl  
belongs_to :criteria, as: control

TextControl
belongs_to :criteria, as: control
```

And be able to query along the lines of:

```
criteria.controls  
# displays all controls (text, scale, etc.) 

criteria.controls.each { ... }
```

What I've looked at so far:
-RailsCasts' episodes on polymorphic associations and seems like this isn't a good use case.
-Dozens of rails associations posts on here but have failed to find anything directly relevant.
-Rails docs.

Are there any common patterns for implementing something like the above in Rails?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022802/multi-table-inheritance-with-rails-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polymorphic setup is good, but this is one place where Rails cannot help you. You have two options. Write the methods yourself:

```
class Criteria

  def controls
    scale_controls + text_controls
  end

  def scale_controls
    ScaleControl.where(criteria_id: id)
  end

  def text_controls
    TextControl.where(criteria_id: id)
  end
end
```

Or you can implement a reverse polymorphic join table. It sounds scary, but it isn't too bad.

```
class CriteriaControl < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :criteria
  belongs_to :control, polymorphic: true # so it must include both a control_id and control_type in its table schema
end
```

Now both of the controls `has_one :criteria_control` and `has_one :criteria, :through => :criteria_control`.

Criteria then `has_many :criteria_controls` and you can define the controls method as such:

```
def controls
  criteria_controls.map(&:control)
end
```

But the real question is "why can't Rails write that?"

When Rails build associations, it is just abstractions over the underlying SQL. Here, Rails cannot gather all of the `controls` because it doesn't know which tables to look in. It first executes `SELECT * FROM criteria_controls WHERE criteria_id = 231231`. Then it can use the `control_type` and `control_id` to find the individual controls in their respective tables.